# get value out of jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

How do you get the value set in this plugin out again?

Example below shows a variable I want available on the page anywhere I need to call it. put all I get is undefined?

**plugin.js**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        options.val ++;
        // access and modify 'somevar' here so that it gets modified
        // in the function which called a plugin

    };
})(jQuery);
```

**script on page**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var somevar = {val: 5};
        $(document).myPlugin(somevar);
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(somevar.val);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your somevar is declared local in the first $(document).ready(), to be accessible in the second one you should rather do :

```
<script>
    var somevar;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        somevar = {val: 5};
        $(document).myPlugin(somevar);

    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(somevar.val);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It still get somevar is undefined with that

Comment: ok when i move it out of the    success: function(data){ it works why?

Comment: This code has been tested here just a second ago, and it works. Let me explain you : by moving the var somevar; outside of your function() {}, you make a global reference, so it means that you will be able to access it everywhere in your code.

Comment: this appears to be true, however for some reason within the  success function of my ajax call it appears is the only place i cannot access the var? anyone know why?

Comment: I think you should post your whole code, otherwise I cannot help

Comment: Ok, thanks for above this works. the issues is with within any  $.ajax call. reason being (from googling) is that you cannot access a var because it excuses after.